# Red Black Tree insertion, I think I might have the rotations messed up

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, red-black-tree

I have been trying to create a red black tree that only implements an insert, search, and in-order traversal method so that I can compare it to a similar AVL tree I made previously. I have used all of the algorithms that are found in the Cormen text: Introduction to Algorithms, but for some reason I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

For example, when I insert a, b, then c and try to do an in-order traversal, I am losing c. I have gone over the algorithms in the text about 10 times to make sure I have everything right and I can't seem to find any mistakes.

Can anyone tell me if I am doing the `insertFix()` method correctly, as well as the rotations.

Below is my header file to give you an idea of how I set up the nodes:

```
class RBT
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        int count;                  // counts the number of times the string has been inserted
        std::string  data;          // Storage for String Data
        node         *parent;       // pointer to this node's parent
        node         *LCH;          // pointer to this node's left child
        node         *RCH;          // pointer to this node's right child
        bool         isRed;         // bool value to specify color of node
    };

    node *root;                     // pointer to the tree's root node
    node *nil;                      // nil node used to implement RBT(aka sentinel)
    void traverse(node *t);         // perform an in-order traversal
    int  height(node *p);           // gets height of tree
    int  totalNodes(node *p);       // gets total nodes in tree
    int  totalWords(node *p);       // gets total words in tree
    void insertFix(node *z);        // fixes tree if RBT rules are broken
    void RR(node *z);               // performs Right rotation at z
    void LR(node *z);               // performs Left rotation at z

public:
    int  insert(std::string str);   // tries to add str to tree.  Returns the new count for str
    int  search(std::string str);   // searches for str.  Returns count for str, 0 if not found
    void list();                    // prints in-order traversal of tree  
    void getHeight();               // prints the height of tree
    void getTotal();                // prints the total number of nodes in the tree, as well as total number of words
    void getComparisons();          // prints the number of comparisons used
    RBT();                          // constructor -- just builds an empty tree with a NULL root pointer
    int  numComp;                   // tracks number of comparisons, only counts for search and insert commands
};
```

And here is my `insertFix()` method, which is ran after a normal insertion that you would find in any ordinary binary search tree:

```
void RBT::insertFix(node *z)
{
    // Private method to fix any rules that might be broken in the RBT.
    // Takes a starting node z, as an input parameter and returns nothing,
    // except for a happy feeling knowing the you are not breaking any RBT laws.
    // Definitions of placeholder nodes used in this method:
    // z  = z
    // y  = left or right uncle of z  

    node *y;

    while (z->parent->isRed)
    {
        if(z->parent == z->parent->parent->LCH)
        {
            y = z->parent->parent->RCH;
            if(y->isRed)
            {
                z->parent->isRed = false;
                y->isRed = false;
                z->parent->parent->isRed = true;
                z = z->parent->parent;
            }
            else
            {
                if( z == z->parent->RCH)
                {
                    z = z->parent;
                    RBT::LR(z);
                }
                z->parent->isRed = false;
                z->parent->parent->isRed = true;
                RBT::RR(z);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            y = z->parent->parent->LCH;
            if(y->isRed)
            {
                z->parent->isRed = false;
                y->isRed = false;
                z->parent->parent->isRed = true;
                z = z->parent->parent;
            }
            else
            {
                if( z == z->parent->LCH)
                {
                    z = z->parent;
                    RBT::RR(z);
                }
                z->parent->isRed = false;
                z->parent->parent->isRed = true;
                RBT::LR(z);
            }
        }
    }
    root->isRed = false;
}
```

Below are my two rotation methods, one is a Right Rotation (RR), and the other is a Left Rotation (LR):

```
void RBT::LR(node *x)
{
    // Method to perform a Left Rotation at Node z. Takes a node pointer
    // as a parameter. Returns void.

    node *y; // y is x's right child
    y = x->RCH;
    x->RCH = y->LCH;
    if (y->LCH != nil) {y->LCH->parent = x;}
    y->parent = x->parent;
    if (x->parent == nil) {root = y;}
    else
    {
        if (x == x->parent->LCH) {x->parent->LCH = y;}
                            else {x->parent->RCH = y;}
    }
    y->LCH = x;
    x->parent = y;
}

void RBT::RR(node *x)
{
    // Method to perform a Left Rotation at Node z. Takes a node pointer
    // as a parameter. Returns void.

    node *y; // y is x's left child
    y = x->LCH;
    x->LCH = y->RCH;
    if (y->RCH != nil) {y->RCH->parent = x;}
    y->parent = x->parent;
    if (x->parent == nil) {root = y;}
    else
    {
        if (x == x->parent->RCH) {x->parent->RCH = y;}
                            else {x->parent->LCH = y;}
    }
    y->RCH = x;
    x->parent = y;
}
```

I know this is a lot of code to look over, but I am at my wits end trying to find out what I am doing wrong. I have a feeling I am messing up the pointers somewhere in one of the rotations but I can't figure out where. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: After this "normal insertion", do you set the children to nil , colour the node red and then call insertFix()?

Comment: @quasiverse Yes those are the last things I do before I call insertFix()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the insertFix() function, in this section:

```
        else
        {
            if( z == z->parent->RCH)
            {
                z = z->parent;
                RBT::LR(z);
            }
            z->parent->isRed = false;
            z->parent->parent->isRed = true;
            RBT::RR(z);
        }
```

you should change

```
            RBT::RR(z);
```

to

```
            RBT::RR(z->parent->parent);
```

Same as the left rotate case in the same function:

```
            RBT::LR(z);
```

to

```
            RBT::LR(z->parent->parent);
```

Comment: This fixed it for me! I can't believe I was missing this. I guess I was just too tired and was looking it over. Thanks a ton!